# How can I select (or copy) text from a Word 2010 ActiveX label?

Tags: vba, activex, ms-word, word-2010

A Word 2010 document has an ActiveX label that displays some text. Is there any way to make the text selectable, or otherwise copy-able, from a user's point of view, so he can paste it somewhere else?

Use case: I give the form to someone, they fill it out and return it to me. The element in question is a Label which, when double clicked, produces UserForm1 which has a ListBox on it. Once one or more selections are made and the user presses OK on UserForm1, the Label in the Word doc gets updated. I then receive the form back, and want to right click the label, copy the text, and paste it into an email.

Comment: From the user point of view? And why not relying on a textbox? You might change its format such that it would look like a label.

Comment: if you want to do it (get text of the label) with vba it's possible...

Comment: @varocarbas from the user's point of view. I tried a TextBox, but the problem I found with that is once the user had selected a few items in the ListBox and pressed OK, the selected items were indeed transferref to the text box but not all items were in view; I had to scroll up within the text box to get to the top. This screenshot shows the difference between a TextBox and a Label being used: 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wgoj7x3s6ofxpae/word2010a.png

Comment: @KazJaw Yes, I do know how to retrieve and store the text of the label... the rub is that this "selectable text/copy-ability" functionality has to be done by the user, though... so select the text + copy, or right-click + copy.

Comment: You have full control on the textbox, you can change its size, relocate the text on it, add scroll bars, etc. all this at runtime and on account of the text inputted by the user. You can emulate the label properties on any front and go beyond its capabilities (by far). Regarding what KazJaw said about being possible to copy the text in the label, he meant retrieving the contents at runtime (this is easy), but allowing users to copy/paste its text is not possible; labels are just for displaying. If you want to allow users to interact with text, VBA expects you to rely on textbox-like controls.

Comment: PS: just to clarify (before someone comes with a magical solution). Possible is possible (almost everything is possible); you might associate your code to the click event of the label and take its text (allow the user to copy it via normal right-click menu would be much more difficult). But what would be the point? You have a control giving you all what the label does + 1000 times more; why restricting yourself? Is not better to learn to use the more-accounting control properly?

Comment: I stumbled upon the answer and will post the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, at least from an end-user's point of view. Let me explain.

I started out wanting to achieve this with a Label, but soon found I couldn't copy the text that was displayed there using conventional ctrl-c or right-click > copy.

So, I switched it up to a TextBox. This worked somewhat, and the data was displayed, though with one flaw: Word 2010 seems to put a bunch of unselectable space between the last line in the TextBox and the bottom of the TextBox, making most the contents hidden until you scrolled back up to the top of it.

Here's what it looked like:

[image: Comparison of TextBox vs Label approach before the fix]

Notice all the empty, unselectable space below the last item in the list?

The solution to my problem of 100% of the text not being displayed in the box was to use this line of code, which places the cursor at the top of the text after the values are placed in the TextBox:

```
ThisDocument.functionalComponentsTextBox.SelStart = 0
```

This basically simulates the user manually clicking in the TextBox and pressing the Up key until he reaches the top of the TextBox. With that, the selections from the ListBox are now stored in the TextBox, the contents of which can be copied and pasted wherever as part of our business processes.

Here's what it looks like after: a perfect match when compared to the properly-displayed Label approach! Added bonus: the text is selectable, and the TextBox is customizable so I removed the border from it... can't tell the difference!

[image: Comparison of TextBox vs Label approach after the fix]